# Use-AzureHDInsightCluster throws error

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to use the Use-AzureHDInsightCluster powershell cmdlet

```
Use-AzureHDInsightCluster "mycluster" -Subscription (Get-AzureSubscription -Current).SubscriptionId
```

but I get the following error. Not sure where to start as I'm new to this.

```
Use-AzureHDInsightCluster : An error occurred while sending the request.
At line:1 char:1
+ Use-AzureHDInsightCluster "mycluster" -Subscription (Get-AzureSubscription -Cu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Use-AzureHDInsightCluster], HttpRequestException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.
PSCmdlets.UseAzureHDInsightClusterCmdlet
```

EDIT I've added the debug flag and I get a little more information

```
DEBUG: Severity: Error
One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken       cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.PSCmdlets.UseAzureHDInsightClusterCmdlet.EndProcessing()
An error occurred while sending the request.
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Cmdlet.Commands.CommandImplementations.UseAzureHDInsightClusterCommand.<End
Processing>d__0.MoveNext()
Unable to connect to the remote server
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions    70.37.71.239:8443
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6,  Socket& socket,
IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message is not very helpful, isn't it.  PowerShell has some common switches.  Two of them are helpful for debugging.  They are -debug and -verbose.  Retry the command with the two switch and get the detailed information.

Is "mycluster" a valid cluster name?  Is it a name you used for this post?  Can you test the Windows Azure connection using the following commands:

Get-AzureSubscription
Get-AzureHDInsightCluster

If you don't receive your subscriptions nor your cluster list.  You might need to fix your connection first.  For information on connecting to your Azure account, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/install-and-configure-windows-powershell/.

Answer (score -1):

Remove WindowsAzureProfile.xml from below folder and try again:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Windows Azure Powershell